# Android: ArrayList and app memory

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a messaging application, in which the received messages are stored in an SQLite database. Every time the main fragment is loaded, the messages are loaded into an ArrayList, and the ArrayList is passed to a RecyclerView for display.

There is one thought that's been bugging me - what if there are too many messages in the database? The ArrayList may end up consuming too much memory and then the app may crash.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You could load only a limited amount of messages, and when you scroll down, you load more.

Comment: @PeterBruins That is an option, yes, but I was wondering how applications like WhatsApp do it, where old messages remain in the list too.

Comment: @UdbhavJain There is posibility they can delete old messages and load it when you scroll up. If not then they probably don't delete it. I think messages aren't that heavy to worry about it

Comment: @UdbhavJain, are you sure they retain all the messages in list at all times? I honestly doubt it. For the reasons you said yourself, having all messages in list at all times consumes memory, and regardless of how little memory one message needs, there'll come a time when it adds up to huge amount. What they probably do is store more messages than they show on one page and load more pages as user scrolls. It's also evidenced by slight slowdowns when scrolling histories with a lot of messages - the slowdown is from loading more pages and discarding ones that are not needed anymore.

Comment: If you look at Whatsapp, when you scroll down, the scroll bar shrinks. This means that the size of ArrayList is increasing. So they may be doing a close solution to Peter's solution.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov That seems feasible - dynamic loading of messages based on scrolling.

Comment: then use [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) adapter as a base class

Comment: so your adapter would look like: `class MyAdapter extends CursorRecyclerAdapter...`, instead of `class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter...`

Comment: @pskink How fast is it? Loading from storage to the RecyclerView doesn't seem like a good idea on paper.

Comment: what do you mean? did you use `CursorAdapter` before? was is slow?

Comment: @pskink Well, the loading of messages from database to ArrayList is only done once, but in case the database is hooked up to the RecyclerView directly, there will be many read operations from the storage. Anyway, it's just speculation on my part. I will give it a try, seems more convenient than scroll listeners.

Comment: no, not at all - `SQLiteCursor` extends `AbstractWindowedCursor`, see `AbstractWindowedCursor` and `CursorWindow` documentation for more details